# java.util.zip.DataFormatException: unknown compression method at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)

Tags: arrays, firebird, unzip, inflate

I wanted to decompress a compressed data from my Firebird DB and chosed to use **inflater class** but I get that Exception! Can u please give me some tipps ! 
Where is a problem or how can I proceed better to decompress such byte array File!!

Here is my code:

```
byte[] ekgDaten = blobres.getBlinhalt();
         System.out.println(ekgDaten.length);
         if(ekgDaten != null && ekgDaten.length !=0){
             // Check if the data is compressed
             if(ekgDaten[0]== 80 && ekgDaten[1] == 75){
                 // Create a decompressor and give it the data to decompress
                 Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();               
                 decompressor.setInput(ekgDaten); 
                 ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream(ekgDaten.length);

                 // Decompress the data
                 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                   try{
                    while(true){
                        int count = 0;
                            try {
                                count = decompressor.inflate(buf);
                            } catch (DataFormatException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(TbblobsFacadeREST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        if(count==0 && decompressor.finished()){
                        break;
                        }else if(count == 0){
                            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException("Bad zip data, size: " + ekgDaten.length);
                            }else{
                        baos.write(buf, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                   }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){

                   }finally{
                   decompressor.end();
                   }
                    // Get decompressed Data
                    byte[] decompressed = baos.toByteArray();
                    map.put(ekgTyp, decompressed);
             }else{
                 map.put(ekgTyp, ekgDaten);
             }
         }
         i++;
     }
    return map;
```

here is the output:

```
INFO: UREKGSIGN
INFO: 115200
INFO: URYEKGSIGN
INFO: 740845
SCHWERWIEGEND: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: unknown compression method
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:256)
    at de.ekg_android.service.TbblobsFacadeREST.getDaten(TbblobsFacadeREST.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at $Proxy130.getDaten(Unknown Source)
    at de.ekg_android.service.__EJB31_Generated__TbblobsFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.getDaten(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:276)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1053)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1043)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:406)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:477)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

INFO: URYIKGSIGN
INFO: 0
INFO: URYEKGVERM
INFO: 0
INFO: UBEKGSIGN
INFO: 1574863
SCHWERWIEGEND: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: unknown compression method
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:256)
    at de.ekg_android.service.TbblobsFacadeREST.getDaten(TbblobsFacadeREST.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at $Proxy130.getDaten(Unknown Source)
    at de.ekg_android.service.__EJB31_Generated__TbblobsFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.getDaten(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:276)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1053)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1043)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:406)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:477)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

INFO: UBIKGSIGN
INFO: 0
INFO: UBEKGVERM
INFO: 0
INFO: ULBDMDAT
INFO: 7224
INFO: URTRAINEKG
INFO: 149334
SCHWERWIEGEND: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: unknown compression method
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:256)
    at de.ekg_android.service.TbblobsFacadeREST.getDaten(TbblobsFacadeREST.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    ......
```

thank u in advance

Comment: What are the first several bytes of what you are trying to decompress?  It is likely that you are trying to decode zlib with a gzip decoder, or vice versa.

Comment: Normally I've found that the bytes are compressed with PKZip because all begin with PK and I have read that I had to use the Inflate constructor ** Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();** I've used that and now I get an other error **java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths **

Comment: The first bytes are 50 4B 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 008B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.util.zip.inflater` decodes the zlib format, not the zip format.  From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html):

> This class provides support for general purpose decompression using
>   the popular ZLIB compression library.

You need to use [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) to read zip files.

Comment: thank you for your Help. The Problem is that I don't have a compressed file to decode that but I have to call this data from a database(Firebird)! and I recognise this data on the fackt that it biginns with PK when I try to view them with an editor.

Comment: Can't you just use a ZipInputStream?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I don't have  a zipped file with a concret filename but I have to get compressed bytes from a database with a sql statment( In some viewer I recognise them with a beginning PK). So I have tried to use ZipInputStream and by the constructor I miss the file name

Comment: [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) does not take a file, it takes an `InputStream` (eg from your `Blob`, or by directly calling `getBinaryStream()` on your resultset. So you don't need a file (I think you are confusing it with `ZipFile`).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Inflater decompressor = new Inflater(true);
```

instead of just

```
Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();
```

It will give some compatibility with other zip engines.

Comment: Do you have any explanation for why this is? I was having a similar problem and this fixed it. FWIW it's inflating data that the standard issue .Net Deflater touched.